# Elastic search results are not as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a field indexed with custom analyzer with the below configuration

```
 "COMPNAYNAME" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "textAnalyzer"
        }

 "textAnalyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "char_filter" : [ ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "ngram_tokenizer"
            }

 "tokenizer" : {
            "ngram_tokenizer" : {
              "type" : "ngram",
              "min_gram" : "2",
              "max_gram" : "3"
            }
          }
```

While I'm searching for a text "ikea" I'm getting the below results

Query :

```
GET company_info_test_1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "COMPNAYNAME": {"query": "ikea"}
    }
  }
}
```

Fallowing are the results,

```
1.mikea
2.likeable
3.maaikeart
4.likeables
5.ikea b.v.  <------
6.likeachef
7.ikea breda <------
8.bernikeart
9.ikea duiven
10.mikea media
```

I'm expecting the exact match result should be boosted more than the rest of the results.
Could you please help me what is the best way to index if I have to search with exact match as well as with fizziness.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the ngram tokenizer also at search time. The usual way of doing it is to have ngrams kick in at indexing time (to produce prefix, infix, suffix tokens) and then use the `standard` analyzer at search time... otherwise you're gonna lose in precision and match too many irrelevant documents. You can already improve what you have just by adding `"search_analyzer": "standard"` to your field mapping.

Comment: @MoulaliShaik did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: Yeah you're right. But in my case I have to perform fuzziness as well.
I tried the below query and it helped me pushing my result up.

`
"query":
    {"bool":
      {
        "should": [
          {
            "span_first": {
              "match": {
                "span_term": {
                  "HANDELSNM": "ikea"
                }
              },
              "end": 3
            }
          },
          {
              "match": {
                "HANDELSNM": {
                  "query": "ikea"}
            }
          }
          
        ]}
    }
`

Answer (score 2):

> You can use [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) along with `"search_analyzer": "standard"` Refer this to know more about [search_analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html)

**As pointed out by @EvaldasBuinauskas you can also use [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) here, if you want the tokens to be generated from the beginning only and not from the middle.**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and result

**Index Data:**

```
{ "title": "ikea b.v."}
{ "title" : "mikea" }
{ "title" : "maaikeart"}
```

**Index Mapping**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "max_ngram_diff": 50
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "ikea"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "normal",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 0.1499838,    <-- note this
                "_source": {
                    "title": "ikea b.v."
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "normal",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.13562363,    <-- note this
                "_source": {
                    "title": "mikea"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "normal",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.083597526,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "maaikeart"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using `edge_ngram` instead of `ngram`. This wouldn't produce tokens from the middle of word.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas yes we can use ```edge_ngrams``` also here if OP wants token to be generated from the beginning only. Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas if you liked the answer, please don't forget to upvote this as well 